# Why don't we consider pressure as the driving agency for motion, instead of force, because the force applied is on an area/part of the body only?

Tags: classical-mechanics

Because the force applied on a body obviously would act on a particular area, and not the whole body.

Comment: coz you imagine a point particle and then pressure would be infinite.

Comment: What do you mean by "*the driving agency for motion*"? You can calculate accelaration using pressure as well $a=F/m=\int_A p(x,y) dxdy/m$.

Comment: Forces don't necessarily act "on a particular area." For example gravity (in Newtonian mechanics) acts on a *volume* of material, not an area.

Comment: You really need to bone up on vectors and scalars.  Force is a vector while pressure is a scalar.  They both have their place in physics, but their purposes are very different.

Comment: Motion without direction won't be much informative. So vector quantity force is required . Also for a complex body we can think to apply force at the centre of mass but if we take pressure neither the direction would be clear nor the area element (think about an irregular body what area element would you consider!) .Rest of the points others have provided

Answer (score 0):

Because it's a lot easier to work with. You could use pressure to calculate how an object will move/behave but you would have to work out the average pressure acting on the body and multiply it by the surface area which would give you the force anyway.

It is similar to how we model gravity to be acting on an object's center of mass even though in reality it is acting on every atom in the object separately